# I am not able to generate a Javascript based CRUD UI front end for my RESTful webservices back end written in Java as per JAX-RS specification

Tags: rest, backbone.js, java-ee-7

I have created the following RESTful web service in Java using Netbeans IDE:

```
package entities.service;

import entities.Product;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@Path("entities.product")
public class ProductFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Product> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DemoBackendPU")
private EntityManager em;

public ProductFacadeREST() {
    super(Product.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void create(Product entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Product entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Product find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Product> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Product> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}

@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

}
```

The Cross Origin Resource Sharing Filter located in a separate package is outlined below.

```
package util;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class NewCrossOriginResourceSharingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext response) {
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
}

}
```

On navigating to the web service URL I am able to see XML representation of the product entity as below.

```
<products>
<product>
<description>Good</description>
<id>1</id>
<name>Microsoft 01</name>
<price>5500</price>
<quantity>10</quantity>
</product>
<product>
<description>Good</description>
<id>2</id>
<name>Microsoft 02</name>
<price>6500</price>
<quantity>20</quantity>
</product>
....
....
....
</products>
```

However on running the HTML page located in a different project and consuming the above RESTful web service I am getting the following errors and the grid is not populating with data.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (16:33:56:252 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8080/DemoBackend/webresources/entities.product/

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "The web service URL above".

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.

The response had HTTP status code 500. (16:33:56:254 | error, javascript)
  at public_html/Products.html

I am making use of a Backbone.js controller.

It may be noted that my client side HTML 5 web page is running at a domain different from the RESTful web service domain.

Why am I getting an Internal Server Error and why XMLHttpRequest is unable to load the REST resource? Why is it saying "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Is my Cross Origin Resource Sharing Filter missing something? Please help.

Comment: You should also post the exception itself. A 500 error can be a lot of stuff...

Comment: Getting cors to work is a bit fiddly. Compare what you have to other examples of specifying cors headers, if I look at this example, your allowed-headers field is lacking the 'options' header: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ . I know you're not using Spring, but cors is not technology specific. (search for 'Filter requests for CORS')